# Export XML table excel sheet into cell

Tags: xml, excel, export-to-excel

Using **excel Developer** I can convert a data table into `XML` file using a template.

It is possible to load this `XML` file content as `String` to a cell in another sheet?

e.g.,

**Sheet 1**

```
       A       B     C     ...

 1    col1   col2   col3
 2    a      1      z
 3    b      2      x
 4    c      3      w
```

This table can be exported using a template as

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<conf xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <data>
        <col1>a</col1>
        <col2>1</col2>
        <col3>z</col3>
    </data>
    <data>
        <col1>b</col1>
        <col2>2</col2>
        <col3>x</col3>
    </data>
    <data>
        <col1>c</col1>
        <col2>3</col2>
        <col3>w</col3>
    </data>
</conf>
```

How can I put this XML as `String` into **Sheet2** in **A1** cell?

Probably the best way is to create a macro button that can export as XML and post the value into the cell. If is true, how can I do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found an easy way to do it.

Using a macro:

```
Sub TestXML()
 Dim strContactData As String
 Dim myWb As Excel.Workbook
 Set myWb = ActiveWorkbook

 myWb.XmlMaps("configuration_Map").ExportXml Data:=strContactData

 Worksheets("SHEET_NAME").Cells(LINE_NUMBER, COL_NUMBER) = strContactData



End Sub
```